# Getting the src of an image in a curled html with dom

Tags: php, dom, xpath

```
function getPage($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}

$page = getPage(trim('http://localhost/test/test.html'));


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xp->query("//img[@class='wallpaper']");
```

I'm trying to find all images with a class `wallpaper` and now I'm stuck to that point. I tried to `var_dump($result)` but it's giving me a weird `object(DOMNodeList)[3]`. How do i finally get the src of the image?

Answer (score 2):

`$result` is a `DOMNodeList` object.

You can find out how many items it contains with

```
$count = $result->length;
```

You access items individually using [`DOMNodeList::item()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php)

```
if ($result->length > 0) {
    $first = $result->item(0);
    $src = $first->getAttribute('src');
}
```

You can also iterate it like an array, eg

```
foreach ($result as $img) {
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: @alex Thanks for the typo fix. Some weird downvotes flying around here

Comment: I've +1'd because I can't see anything that would warrant a downvote.

Comment: Hi, i updated the question a bit, it works if `$page` is a simple string, but it doesn't if `$page` is from a cURL'ed data. I'm getting a `result->length` of 0

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Phil's answer, you can also grab the `src` attribute directly in your xpath query instead of grabbing the `img` element:

```
$srcs = array();
$result = $xp->query("//img[@class='wallpaper']/@src");
foreach($result as $attr) {
    $srcs[] = $attr->value;
}
```

Comment: Nice, especially if the attribute is all the OP is after

Comment: Hi, i updated the question a bit, it works if `$page` is a simple string, but it doesn't if `$page` is from a cURL'ed data.

Comment: This really ought to be a different question. Just `var_dump($page)` to verify that it is in fact an html string. Frankly you should just use `$dom->loadHTMLFile($theurl)`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the images in the `DOMNodeList` with a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($result as $img) {
   echo $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

You could get the first with `echo $result->item(0)->getAttribute('src')`. You may want to confirm the `DOMNodeList` has items by checking the `length` property of `$result`.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo $result->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: `$result` won't have a `getAttribute()` method.